# Duvida em consulta de dominios

Tags: php, api

Fala galera, preciso de informações concedidas por meios de whois, de diversos dominios, que podem terminar em .com, .br, .net, etc.
 Com o nosso provedor br o nicbr sem problema, já estou usando rdap deles que retorna uma maravilha de json tudo bonitinho tudo bacana, o problema é com o resto, pelo que vi o ICANN(Corporação da Internet para Atribuição de Nomes e Números) é responsável por tudo, procurei por apis webservices etc mas nada, fui em busca dos provedores que esses grandes vendedores de host usam, ex:godaddy, hostgator, etc, encontrei vários, tudo muito nebuloso.
Segue alguns que eu percebi que eles fazem intermédio, ou seja, de alguma forma eles consomem as informações de modo bonito e bacana, sem dar file_get_contents e tratar string, talvez js e xml o que seria o ideal:
http://whois.internic.net/
http://whois.afilias.net/
http://whois.verisign-grs.com/
http://whois.markmonitor.com/
http://whois.afilias.info/
Encontrei tbm o https://www.robowhois.com que me pareceu perfeito, porém pede uma key_api e password que não faço ideia do que seja.
Ajuda ai galera preciso das informações de uma porrada de dominios e persistir em banco.

Comment: https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whois-api-doc.php

Answer (score 0):

O robowhois está desligado, tem um aviso na página, eu já usei uma vez esta API para isso (https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whois-api-doc.php), mas como uma API de terceiros acho que ela fica paga após 500 requisições por dia ou algo assim, tem que dar uma olhada melhor nela, mas acho que resolve teu problema

---- Edição ----

Procurando lá acho que a API deles está somente paga agora, não achei nada free, fui catar e achei esta (https://jsonwhois.com/) que até 500 requesições não tem mensalidade. Ele tem exemplos de códigos em várias linguagens ali também para tu ajudar a implementar

Comment: valeu Evandro, vou dar uma olhada, tbm vi rdap mas a documentação é extensa, vou precisar de um tempo para pegar as "manhas".

Comment: Qualquer dúvida pode perguntar que tentamos ajudar

Comment: Já tenho uma na mão hehe. Não é o primeiro que pede Token token=<Api Key>, manja? é o password da propria ferramenta?

Comment: É como se fosse, ao invés de pedir um login, como é para realizar requisições assíncronas, ele pede o token. Geralmente tu consegue o teu no dashboard da ferramenta, conseguiu achar teu token? A ferramenta gera para ti e tu coloca na tua implementação em cada chamada